# Add Key, Value pair to new dict

Tags: python

I have an existing list of Key, Value pairs in my current dictionary called `total_list`. I want to check my list to see if the length of each `Key == 1` in `total_list`, I want to add that key and its value pair to a new dictionary. This is the code that I've come up with.

```
total_list = {104370544: [31203.7, 01234], 106813775: [187500.0], 106842625: [60349.8]}

diff_so = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in total_list:
    if len(total_list[key]) == 1:
        diff_so[key].append[val]
        total_list.pop[key]
```

But I keep getting an error with

> "cannot unpack non-iterable int object".

I was wondering if there's anyway for me to fix this code for it to run properly?

Comment: what is `total_list`?

Comment: its a dictionary list that contains key, value pairs

Comment: How do you check length of key? string of one character?

Comment: len is checking for the total amount of values within that specific key. because in my total_list some key have multiple value pairs. for ex. {4:1,2,3} this would have length of 3.

Comment: Are you just looking for `{k: v for k, v in total_list.items() if len(k) == 1}`?

Comment: yes and I want to add that specific k: v to a new dictionary if len(k) == 1

Comment: Please add a minimal working example to reproduce your error. What is in `total_list` ?

Comment: just updated it with an example.

Comment: Your example hints at checking the length of the *value*, not the key

Comment: yes so if the key contains one value add it to a new dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the OP means a string of one character by length = 1 of the key.

---

You can do this:

```
total_list = [{'abc':"1", 'bg':"7", 'a':"7"}]
new_dict = {}
for i in total_list:
    for k,v in i.items():
        if len(k) == 1:
            new_dict[str(k)] = v
        else:
            pass
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'a': '7'}
```

After edit:

```
total_list = {104370544: [31203.7, 1234], 106813775: [187500.0], 106842625: [60349.8]}

new_dict = {}
for k,v in total_list.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        new_dict[k] = v
    else:
        pass
```

Output:

```
{'106842625': [60349.8], '106813775': [187500.0]}
```

Comment: i have int in my dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You just need a dictionary comprehension

```
diff_so = {k: v for k, v in total_list.items() if len(v) == 1}
```